# curl POST to rest template

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl

```
curl -v POST -d '[23,24]'  https://serverurl/api/list/GetByIds --header "Accept:application/json"  --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer XYZ"
```

The above curl statement returns proper result. I am not sure how to send the same data using Spring RestTemplate.exchange . I don't need the whole code, I just want to know how I can send that list of integers [23,24].

Comment: You can use the exchange(RequestEntity<?> requestEntity, java.lang.Class<T> responseType) method. When you create parametrized RequestEntity you can add List<Integer> as the type of the Request entity. ```RequestEntity<List<Integer>> request = RequestEntity.post(new URI("http://example.com/bar")).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(<actual list here>);```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
integers.add(23);
integers.add(24);

restTemplate.exchange("url", 
    HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(integers), new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Integer>>() {
});
```

Replace `List<Integer>` in `new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Integer>>()` with your response model.